# QR Code Alternative?

Tags: android, qr-code

I am using QR Codes for a project where I need to put a service configuration inside the QR Code. However the configuration is a little big (2 kb) and I have to split the data in order to generate QR Codes. Usually for a 2 kb file I get 8 QR Codes. If I increase my QR Code split margin the QR Code would become illegible and the phone could not read it.
In my scenario I would not have access to the Internet with the mobile phone, putting links in the QR Code is out of question.
I would like to ask if there are something similar to QR Code but allowing to put more data.
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to save anything into a QR code that is not meant to be scanned in the first place?

Comment: It is meant to be scanned. Maybe I was not very explicit on my question. The QR Code should contain a file configuration (For example JSON data).